# How to create a class with multiple inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, multiple-inheritance

I have this code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age 

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age, indexNr, notes):
        super().__init__(name, last_name, age)
        self.indexNr = indexNr
        self.notes = notes

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age, salary, position):
        super().__init__(name, last_name, age)
        self.salary = salary
        self.position = position

class WorkingStudent(Student, Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age, indexNr, notes, salary, position):
        Student.__init__(name, last_name, age, indexNr, notes)
        Employee.__init__(name, last_name, age, salary, position)
```

I want to create a WorkingStudent instance like this:

```
ws = WorkingStudent("john", "brown", 18, 1, [1,2,3], 1000, 'Programmer')
```

but it's not working, I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'notes'
```

Or what I am doing wrong here? Also, I have already tried `super()` in WorkingStudent class but it calls only the constructor of the first passed class. i.e in this case `Student`

Note: I have already gone through multiple StackOverflow queries but I couldn't find anything that could answer this. (or maybe I have missed).

Comment: This happens because if you create a `Student` directly, the `super()` call will initialize `Person`; but if you create a `WorkingStudent`, then `super()` in `Student` will initialize **`Employee`** instead. That's what's next in the MRO for the class of the actual object. This is why you see `**kwargs` all over the place in frameworks that make heavy use of multiple inheritance.

Comment: "Note: I have already gone through multiple StackOverflow queries but I couldn't find anything that could answer this. (or maybe I have missed)." See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance This should come up for you if you search for `[python] super`; I don't know what you tried, but when the issue seems to be conceptual, start with broader and more highly-upvoted Stack Overflow results.

Comment: Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of explicit classes, use `super()` to pass arguments along the mro:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age 

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age, indexNr, notes, salary, position):
        # since Employee comes after Student in the mro, pass its arguments using super
        super().__init__(name, last_name, age, salary, position)
        self.indexNr = indexNr
        self.notes = notes

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age, salary, position):
        super().__init__(name, last_name, age)
        self.salary = salary
        self.position = position

class WorkingStudent(Student, Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age, indexNr, notes, salary, position):
        # pass all arguments along the mro
        super().__init__(name, last_name, age, indexNr, notes, salary, position)

# uses positional arguments            
ws = WorkingStudent("john", "brown", 18, 1, [1,2,3], 1000, 'Programmer')
# then you can print stuff like
print(f"My name is {ws.name} {ws.last_name}. I'm a {ws.position} and I'm {ws.age} years old.")
# My name is john brown. I'm a Programmer and I'm 18 years old.
```

Check mro:

```
WorkingStudent.__mro__
(__main__.WorkingStudent,
 __main__.Student,
 __main__.Employee,
 __main__.Person,
 object)
```

---

When you create an instance of WorkingStudent, it's better if you pass keyword arguments so that you don't have to worry about messing up the order of arguments.

Since WorkingStudent defers the definition of attributes to parent classes, immediately pass all arguments up the hierarchy using `super().__init__(**kwargs)` since a child class doesn't need to know about the parameters it doesn't handle. The first parent class is Student, so self.IndexNr etc are defined there. The next parent class in the mro is Employee, so from Student, pass the remaining keyword arguments to it, using `super().__init__(**kwargs)` yet again. From Employee, define the attributes defined there and pass the rest along the mro (to Person) via `super().__init__(**kwargs)` yet again.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age 

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, indexNr, notes, **kwargs):
        # since Employee comes after Student in the mro, pass its arguments using super
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.indexNr = indexNr
        self.notes = notes

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, salary, position, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.salary = salary
        self.position = position

class WorkingStudent(Student, Employee):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # pass all arguments along the mro
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

# keyword arguments (not positional arguments like the case above)
ws = WorkingStudent(name="john", last_name="brown", age=18, indexNr=1, notes=[1,2,3], salary=1000, position='Programmer')
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem: we have a lot of arguments for our most derived class, that need to be used to initialize all the bases. However, in Python's multiple inheritance system with `super()`, the class that will be initialized next depends on an MRO (method resolution order) that may have been determined in another class. Therefore, when we use multiple inheritance, we don't know which class will have its `__init__` called when we use `super()`.

Solution: use consistent names for the parameters, and then take advantage of `**kwargs`, so that each class takes in the (explicitly named) parameters it cares about, and forwards the rest.

That looks like:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age 

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, indexNr, notes, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.indexNr = indexNr
        self.notes = notes

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, salary, position, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.salary = salary
        self.position = position

class WorkingStudent(Student, Employee):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Forcing the client code to use keyword arguments is more work for the clients, but it also helps guard against errors from mistaking the order of positional arguments.

Answer (score -1):

**This is the easiest way to reach your goal.**
If your WorkingStudent class inherite Student and Employee class like this ,

```
class WorkingStudent(Student, Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age, indexNr, notes, salary, position):
        Student.__init__(self, name, last_name, age, indexNr, notes)
        Employee.__init__(self, name, last_name, age, salary, position)


ws = WorkingStudent("john", "brown", 18, 1, [1, 2, 3], 1000, 'Programmer')
print(ws)
print(ws.name)
print(ws.age)
```

your output will be...

**Output:**

> <**main**.WorkingStudent object at 0x7fc6c4d8ba10>
> john
> 18
> [1, 2, 3]